# How to fix "show Thresholed image on winform CLR "

Tags: winforms, opencv, camera

[image]

I use the function `DrawCVImage()` to put the video on winform CLR. I worked for HSV image, normal image except the thresholded image. 
the thresholded screen separated into 3 sections @@
picture number3: I used `imshow()`;
picture number4 : i used `DrawCVImage()`;

thank you,
[image]

Comment: Could you provide a [Minimal, complete and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of what you tried?

Comment: @Astrom
I dont know how to post the image for my comments
I used this for drawing
void DrawCVImage(System::Windows::Forms::Control^ control, cv::Mat& colorImage)
  {
   System::Drawing::Graphics^ graphics = control->CreateGraphics();
   System::IntPtr ptr(colorImage.ptr());
   System::Drawing::Bitmap^ b = gcnew System::Drawing::Bitmap(colorImage.cols, 
    colorImage.rows, colorImage.step, System::Drawing::Imaging::PixelFormat::Format24bppRgb, ptr);
   System::Drawing::RectangleF rect(0, 0, control->Width, control->Height);
   graphics->DrawImage(b, rect);
   delete graphics;
  }